# Can you trigger methods in ion-select, the same as you would a (click)="method()"

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

So I am having some issues with ion-select. I have tried for hours to try and get various things to work.
Basically, I have a list of WordPress posts. I want the user to be able to select how many columns to view in an ion-select. 
I have achieved this perfectly fine with buttons, however, for a greater selection of options, I want to use the ion-select.

I have tried multiple tutorials but don't fully understand. I have tried with ionChange but to no avail.

HTML - As I mentioned, my buttons work perfectly fine so I believe the basic methods to update NgClass are working fine.

```
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Columns</ion-label>
      <ion-select #columnCount (ionChange)="onChange($event)" placeholder=" Select One">
        <ion-select-option [value]="applyOneCol()">One</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option [value]="applyTwoCol()">Two</ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>


    <div text-center class="col-buttons">
      <ion-button (click)="applyTwoCol()">Two Columns</ion-button>
      <ion-button (click)="applyOneCol()">One Column</ion-button>
    </div>




 <ion-row class="row">
      <ion-col [ngClass]="getCurrentColCount()" ngDefaultControl no-padding *ngFor=" let post of posts">
```

TS - These work perfectly for the click events on the buttons, but I cannot for the life of me get the same functionality in the ion-select.

```
  public currentColCount = 'one-col';


  applyOneCol() {
    this.currentColCount = 'one-col';
    console.log(this.currentColCount);
  }

  applyTwoCol() {
    this.currentColCount = 'two-col';
    console.log(this.currentColCount);
  }

  getCurrentColCount() {
    return this.currentColCount;
  }

  onChange() {
    console.log(this.currentColCount);
  }
```

I believe its something really simple, but I have tried to use ion-select previously but ended up ditching it for buttons but this time I have no choice but to get ion-select working. I thought it would have been as simple as triggering the methods for each option but I can't even get that to work.

(my ion-select code is a total mashup of various things I've tried and I just got lost so it may look a bit odd)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok first you should use ngModel, and modify the code as follows

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Columns</ion-label>
  <ion-select #columnCount (ionChange)="onChange()" [(ngModel)]=selectedcol' placeholder=" Select One">
    <ion-select-option [value]="one-col'">One</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option [value]="two-col'">Two</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>

onChange()
{
this.currentColcount = this.selectedcol
}
```

on this way, the ngmodel (ie the selcedcol ) will hold the selected option
and you can easily assign it to the currentColcount

you can still eliminate the function,but the above is the most basic one

Comment: reactive forms > ngModel